# What are some good eating habits?

Tags: road-bike, nutrition

I want to get myself back into road cycling. When I first bought my bike I was serious and was riding everyday 20-30 miles. I got burned out because I wasn't eating right.

This time around I want to make sure that my eating habits are in the right place so my energy levels stay high and can support me.

Comment: I highly recommend food.  With a little beer on the side.

Comment: There are probably as many answers to this as there are serious cyclists. See the many questions we have tagged [tag:nutrition]. Is there any way to narrow this question down?

Comment: Chew with your mouth closed and don't talk with your mouth full.  People will think you have poor table manners otherwise.

Comment: Per the FAQ: "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." A quick search of Amazon turns up a number of books addressing this question.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! Please help us narrow this down by making your question more specific. If you want a plan for every thing you should eat, that's really beyond the scope of this site (several books could be written on the topic and it could be specific to you).  How do you know you got burned out because you weren't eating right? What were you eating? What have you tried? Give us more to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that the whole live-strong movement has been losing popularity.  I am a big fan of their [My Plate](http://www.livestrong.com/myplate/) online application for tracking what I eat, and setting goals for what I should be eating.

I think there are a whole bunch of differing opinions about diet out there.  I try to stick to the old common sense approach.  A gallon of ice cream bad.  Eating a bowl of chicken and rice good.  Eating until I hurt bad, eating until I'm satisfied good.

I also believe however that when you are burning large amounts of calories - those calories need to be replaced by healthy things.  That's another thing I like about My Plate.  It helps me offset activity with diet and gives good guides for what my diet is made of.